# Strapi not installing date-fns index.js file when running yarn

Tags: strapi, date-fns

I’m trying to install a Strapi project that I’ve made a few months back on my new laptop and I keep getting the error:

`Error: Cannot find module '/ppl-cms/node_modules/date-fns/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry`

I’ve tried using different node versions, deleting node_modules and yarn.lock files and updating strapi but nothing seems to work. Can’t seem to find that much information online about this topic so I was hoping to find some help here. The date-fns version that is being isntalled is 2.30.0. I’ve read about this problem in some previous versions but not in this one. Any advice?

`Strapi Version: 4.17.0`
`Operating System: macOS Sonoma 14.3.1`
`Database: sqlite`
`Node Version: 20.11.1`
`NPM Version: 10.2.4`
`Yarn Version: 1.22.21`

Comment: Did you try to clear your Yarn and NPM cache.
That may also come from here

Comment: Clearing the yarn cache seemed to work! Thanks a lot!